# Know which script/page is being called by ajax call

Tags: ajax, 404-error

I have to reverse-engineer a wordpress site, which requires some updates, but I am unable to make it work properly at one place. Here, on click of a link, an AJAX call is being made to some page that is returning a 404 error. I am unable to get the exact php script that is being called. Is there any way to get that script or page which is being called by that AJAX call?

Answer (score 0):

Open the website with Web Developer tools or Browser inspection tools ( Firebug )etc and then Run "Console".

Refresh your website and see the Ajax calls. Check the POST window in Ajax call to see action script. That'd tell you the exact function being called.[image: ajax post action]

Comment: The request is if type GET, and then I guess if there is some url rewriting being used internally, then this might not work at all.